# Pass data from directive to main controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I bubble up my directive $scope.posts to my root scope so that my view updates with the data the directive just fetched?

```
var lassoDirectives = angular.module('lassoDirectives', []);
lassoDirectives.directive('autoTable', ['getitems', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            modelname: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'http://local.angular.com/webroot/app/templates/directives/auto-table.html',
        controller: function($scope, getitems) {
            //console.log(parse);
            $scope.deleteItem = function(id) {
                items = getitems.delete({type: $scope.modelname, Id: id});
                posts = getitems.query({type: $scope.modelname});

            }
            $scope.check = function() {
                console.log($scope.data);
                $scope.posts = getitems.query({type: $scope.modelname});
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Why do you to go as far as $rootscope ?

Comment: You could just get hold of $rootScope and set posts there. Are looking for ways to communicate with parent scope to affect the parent ? If yes then you could pass in a function from the parent scope with & param and just call it.

Comment: If you really want to share some common piece of data, why not use Angular Services.. Create a service, and inject it in both controller and directive..

Answer (score 0):

What you should be trying to do is keep your application as modular as possible. In your circumstance accessing `$scope.posts` from other parts of your application would break this modularity.

The is where things like the event pattern fits in. You can `emit` an event from your directive, that is able to be consumed by anything, allowing decoupling. For example:

```
$scope.$emit('posts_arrived', { posts: thePosts });
```

Emit will bubble from the current place in the hierarchy up to the root. If you want to ensure any part of your application can consume the event, you could `$broadcast` from `$rootScope`.

Read [scope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It says in ["Comprehensive Directive API" of AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> **& or &attr** - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of
>   the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name
>   is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localFn:'&myAttr' }, then isolate scope property localFn will point to
>   a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often
>   it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression
>   to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local
>   variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example,
>   if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount
>   value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

So, maybe this is what you want:

1. Write html as follows:

   ```
   &lt;auto-table modelname="amodelname" collect-posts = "CollectPosts(posts)"&gt;&lt;/auto-table&gt;
   ```
2. Write your directive codes like this:

   ```
   var lassoDirectives = angular.module('lassoDirectives', []);
   lassoDirectives.directive('autoTable', ['getitems', function(getitems) {
       return {
           restrict: 'AE',
           scope: {
               data: '=',
               modelname: '=',
               sendBackPosts: '&collectPosts'
           },
           templateUrl: 'http://local.angular.com/webroot/app/templates/directives/auto-table.html',
           link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                   //...
                   scope.posts = getitems.query({type: scope.modelname});
                   scope.sendBackPosts({posts: scope.posts});
           }
       };
   }]);
   ```
3. In your controller codes (maybe in a separate file), write:

   ```
   var lassoDirectives = angular.module('lassoDirectives'); // pay attention here: no '[]' to use a defined module.
   lassoDirectives.controller('MyController', ['$scope',function($scope) {
       $scope.CollectPosts = function( posts ){
           for( var i = 0 ; i < posts.length; i ++ ){
               //...
           }
       }
   }]);
   ```

**Notes:**

i) To inject any service like `getitems`, you not only need to put it in the array as a string, but also need to put it in the function arguments.

ii) The controller definition found in your codes, which is the 'controller' property of a directive definition object, is a different thing from the controller of an angular module, where you are supposed to collect the posts. In the same angularjs documentation page as provided at the beginning, you can find the following about controller property of a directive definition object:

> controller
>
> Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated before
>   the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives (see
>   require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with
>   each other and augment each other's behavior. The controller is
>   injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following locals

I guess, this may not be what you want to do. From the name of your directive, you may want to fetch some data and populate a table. You should define your DOM manipulation logic in the `link` property of the directive definition object instead.

Hope this helps.